# How would I say "Courageous warriors called Samurai?"

Tags: word-choice, translation

How would I go about saying "Courageous warriors called Samurai?
Would さむらいと言うゆうきなせんし make sense?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No 勇気な戦士 does not make sense, because 勇気 is not a na-adjective.

If you want to use 勇気 (you probably do), you have to say 勇気がある and when this modifies a noun (like 戦士), you should use no-ga conversion to get

> 侍という勇気のある戦士

Comment: Ahh you're correct, thank you! I should've checked if it was a na adjective first, I just didn't know how to express "courageous" with a noun properly.

What I was originally trying to write was, "the warriors who rode on horses and were courageous were called "Samurai""

I re-modified my old one with your help, is this sentence okay now?
勇気があって馬に乗って戦士たちは「侍」とよびました。

Comment: It would have been easier if you had asked your full question from the beginning.

Comment: Sorry about that, I thought this alone would be enough, but I figured that my Japanese may not be well-off enough to make sure this sentence was correct. I also wanted to try making the sentence myself without someone translating it completely, that way I could learn better

Comment: How about さむらいと呼ばれている<del>愛と</del>勇気の戦士たち? :)

Comment: @user3682, 勇気があって馬に乗る/馬に乗った/馬に乗って戦う戦士たちは「侍」と呼びました might be better. By the way, are you sure it's not 「騎士」, but 「侍」?

Comment: 「侍という勇気のある戦士」 sounds wordy if I may speak on the native level.  I would either drop the 「の」 as it is unnecessary or use 「勇敢な」 instead.

Comment: Thanks for the help everyone, perhaps I should try "騎士"? I will ask my friend.
Anyways, i'm not sure why Earthliŋ didn't want to help me a second time but that is alright
Once again thanks for all your help

Comment: "the warriors who rode on horses and were courageous were called "Samurai" >> I think you can say... 馬に乗った勇気あるor勇敢な戦士を侍と呼んだ。OR 馬に乗った勇気あるor勇敢な戦士は侍と呼ばれた。(ところで。。。侍って、「騎士」なんでしょうか？そもそも、「騎士」と「戦士」って馬に乗ってるかどうかだけの違い？)

Comment: It's not so much that I didn't want to help you a second time, but I answer questions in my free time and sometimes I run out of free time. I had imagined "Courageous warriors called Samurai" was some sort of slogan (maybe for a poster) that you wanted translated. For such a slogan 「侍という勇気のある戦士」 fits well in my opinion. The comments seem to suggest that you don't want a slogan, but a full sentence. A full sentence may appear in all sorts of contexts, so you'll have to provide the context to get the best answer. You can either try to edit your original question, or ask a new question.